# Live translation IME (Input Method Editor) for Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows, input-method

I'm wondering if there is a live translation IME (Input Method Editor) for Microsoft Windows. Where you type in English, and it gets translated on the fly to a language of choice. Whether it's online or offline.

But I'm talking about Windows IME; that sits in the taskbar and the OS recognizes it as an input method.

Note that I'm NOT referring to **Transliteration**, but rather **Translation**.

So is there such a piece of software?

Comment: I really doubt. Think about it, this is technically almost impossible to implement correctly as the 1st way - checking all input field of all apps - is not really doable considering how different app UIs can be. What if one of the fields was app setting that isn't supposed to be translated? While the 2nd - listening to all inputs and autodetecting words - would need a lot edge cases like using keyboard shortcuts, switching between windows, moving mouse cursor somewhere else in the input, etc.